# How do you find all nodes with exactly N relationships of a single type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some nodes A connected to nodes B via a relationship rel. What query will I write to return all B which are related to exactly 3 A or exactly 4 A or exactly n A via the relation rel? I achieved this for 2 by using the following match clause:

```
MATCH (a1:A)<-[:rel]-(b:B)-[:rel]->(a2:A)
```

I also require to know which 3 A are connected to that B as I need to count the occurrences of that set of 3 A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate by [COUNT](https://neo4j.com/developer/aggregation-returns-functions/#aggregate-count):

```
MATCH (b:B)-[:rel]->(a:A)
WITH b, count(a) AS cnt WHERE cnt = 3 // or for example WHERE cnt IN [3, 4]
RETURN b
```

**Upd:** Try to use the [COLLECT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) and [SIZE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-size) functions if you need to return nodes connected to (:B):

```
MATCH (b:B)-[:rel]->(a:A)
WITH b, 
     collect(a) AS nds WHERE size(nds) = 3
RETURN b, nds
```

Comment: Can this also be used to return what are the 3 nodes of A connected to the B? like B and a1, a2, a3 which are nodes of A, as I actually want to group the number of B by the a1, a2, a3 combinations

Comment: Secondly A and B are not variables. What you meant to write I think was a and b

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be shorter

```
MATCH (b:B)
WHERE size((b)-[:rel]->(:A)) = 3
RETURN b,[(b)-[:rel]->(a:A) | a ] AS nds
```